# Начало работы с Oracle OLAP Option

Tags: oracle, olap, база-данных

Как при установке `Oracle Dstabase Express Edition 11g` включить опцию "OLAP Option" и как начать с нем (OLAP) работать? Ну то есть подключиться к базе, куб создать, и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если не ошибаюсь, Olap только с энтерпрайзом идет в поставке

Comment: Похоже, что так. :(

Comment: а что мешает поставить энтерпрайз?

Comment: В любом случае если уж начинать изучать oracle, то лучше с энтепрайза, а не с кривого XE. Может быть, например, партиции никогда не пригодятся, но пощупать их надо